# Transactions in metamask fails via Alchemy

Tags: alchemy, goerli

All transactions done in metamask fail.
I've followed the docs https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-add-alchemy-rpc-endpoints-to-metamask
and added Goerli.
I tried to send USDC on Goerli and sadly, it's failing.

My MM setup is this
[image]

[image]

Is there anything else I need to setup, please?

Comment: Can you share more details of the failed transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Hi dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

Goerli has been really congested lately and this reflects in high gas prices, your transaction is most likely underpriced. I would recommend using the Sepolia testnet instead!

You can get a Sepolia node on Chainstack for free if you need one :)

1. [Sign up with Chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/user/account/create).
2. [Deploy a node](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/join-a-public-network).
3. [View node access and credentials](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/view-node-access-and-credentials).